# Angular2 HTTP request fails

Tags: angular, angular2-http

This is my first question here. I have a problem with the http requests on an API. When I make the request, the following error shows up on the console:

EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

The content of each files is:

**boot.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/http";

bootstrap(AppComponent,[HTTP_PROVIDERS]);
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTPTestService} from "./services/peli.service";
import {Peli} from "./peli";

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Búsqueda de película</h1>
        <input #titulo placeholder="Buscar...">
        <button class="btn btn-success"     (click)="infoPeli(titulo.value)">Buscar</button>
        <div *ngFor="#peli of pelis">
        <h1>{{peli.Title}}</h1>
        <p>{{peli.Year}}</p>
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [HTTPTestService]
})

export class AppComponent {

pelis:Peli[];

    constructor (private _httpService: HTTPTestService) {}

    infoPeli(nombre:string) {
        this._httpService.buscarPeli(nombre)
            .subscribe(
                data => this.pelis = data,
                error => alert(error),
                () => console.log(this.pelis)
            );
    }
}
```

**peli.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HTTPTestService {
    constructor(private _http:Http) {
    }

    buscarPeli(nombre:string) {
        return this._http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?    t='+nombre+'&y=&plot=short&r=json').map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

**peli.ts**

```
export class Peli{
    Title:string;
    Year:string;
}
```

**And the JSON file that I receive from the request (Input - spiderman):**

```
{"Title":"Spiderman","Year":"1990","Rated":"N/A","Released":"N/A","Runtime":"5 min","Genre":"Short","Director":"Christian Davi","Writer":"N/A","Actors":"N/A","Plot":"N/A","Language":"German","Country":"Switzerland","Awards":"N/A","Poster":"N/A","Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"5.7","imdbVotes":"90","imdbID":"tt0100669","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

I don't know where the problem is, everything seems to be OK...

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `<div *ngFor="#peli of pelis">` element. And you are setting `this.pelis` to be an object here =>

```
.subscribe(
                data => this.pelis = data,
```

And you are getting an

EXCEPTION: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Since pelis is not an array you are getting this error.

For example: 
Instead of

```
data => this.pelis = data
```

Try:

```
data => this.pelis = [data]
```

Comment: I'm new on Angular and I don't know how to solve that. Could you help me to fix it please? It's just a test to practice.

Comment: Thanks! I alter the code in that way: infoPeli(nombre:string) {
        this._httpService.buscarPeli(nombre)
            .subscribe(
                (data)=>{this.pelis = [data.Title, data.Year]},
                error => alert(error),
                () => console.log(this.pelis)
            );
    }With that fix the following error appers in the compiler: Assigned expression type string[] is not assignable to type Peli[]

Comment: Ok! I got the same error in the compiler, but the object appears on the console: ["Spiderman", "1990"] Now the problem is that the data is not shown on the screen.

Comment: With the last fix, the object that appears on the console is: [Object {data=Object}]

Comment: Can you again try without the {} on data

Comment: At last it works! With the solution data => this.pelis = [data], everything goes OK! Thank you very much!